# ñ returns null - jQuery en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, utf-8

I use jQuery to run a function in PHP to get data from the database.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'service.php',
            data: { functie: type, param: radiobutton },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {}
        });
```

Everything works. Except the strings with special characters return as null in the succes function. For example: ñ

The answer for this is here explained: 
[Special characters break json returned to jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084578/special-characters-break-json-returned-to-jquery)

But it doesn't work for me.

In php I tried:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wines");
$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[]=htmlentities($row);
}
```

Who knows how to make sure everything returns in a good way?

Comment: Read: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 1):

In your while statement you're using `htmlentities` on an array, not a string (each key in the array is a column in the database).

You could do either of the following:

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[] = array_map("htmlentities", $row);
}
```

or change your while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $row[$key] = htmlentities($value);
    }
    $array[] = $row;
}
```